# TSQL BITWISE NOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit

The binary representation of integer 170 is `1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0`
Reversing the bits gives `0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1`
That converted to decimal is integer 85.

Why does `SELECT ~170`
return -171?

I am struggling to understand  what I am missing here.

Comment: Try `SELECT ~CAST(170 AS tinyint);` to avoid operating on a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Thanks, that gives the answer I expected, namely, 85.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a byte (8-bits), it's probably a 32-bit number.

Whatever the length (16, 32, or 64), it will have leading `0`s. In 16-bit this looks like:

`0000 0000 1010 1010` becomes `1111 1111 0101 0101` which is -171.

You can do this yourself with windows calculator with programmer mode, decimal, and anything higher than byte selected. Enter 170 and hit NOT and you get -171, and it will show you the bit representations of each.

Another thing to note would be that `1010 1010` is not actually 170, if it is a signed byte. As a signed byte it would be -86. Inverting it in byte mode yields 85, as you expected.

Note also the difference between signed and unsigned bit patterns. The bit length matters, because for signed integers, a number that starts with a `1` is negative, and you get the absolute value of that negative number by inverting the bits and adding one. (see: [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement))

This is why `1010 1010` (as a byte) gives a positive number if you invert it, and why `0000 0000 1010 1010` gives a negative number if you invert it.

For reference, the integral types in SQL Server are:

- **tinyint**: byte (1 byte) (8 bits) (unsigned)
- **smallint**: word (2 bytes) (16 bits) (signed)
- **int**: dword (4 bytes) (32 bits) (signed)
- **bigint**: qword (8 bytes) (64 bits) (signed)

Note that while I described signed bytes, it looks like SQL Server does not have signed bytes at all, and does not have larger unsigned integer types at all. So if you use `tinyint` it will always be unsigned, and if you use anything larger, it will always be signed.

Comment: It it is using 15 bits, you'd get 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 as you suggest. Reversing the bits gives 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 which converted to decimal is 65365 not -171.

Comment: @AAsk `1111 1111 0101 0101` as a signed 16-bit integer is -171. As an *unsigned* 16-bit integer, it's 65365, yes.

Comment: Thank you; that gives me a better grasp of what is happening. However, I find it a little strange since TSL does not (as far as I know) have the functionality to specify INT as signed or unsigned.

Comment: @AAsk it looks like `tinyint`s are always unsigned, and any larger integer type is always signed.